# Httpd error: not accessible symlink with -D FOREGROUND

Tags: fedora, apache-http-server, symbolic-link, httpd, systemd

I'm trying to setup virtual host in Fedora18.

Configuration is following:

- httpd version is 2.4
- user/group - apache/apache
- global document root is /var/www/html
- vhost symlink: /var/www/html/vhost/domain.name -> /project/www.
- all directories from / to /project/www have +x permission

When I start httpd manually (sudo httpd -k start) everything works fine. `ps aux` output for this case:

> apache   23827  0.0  0.0 531040  7184 ?        S    17:16   0:00 httpd -k start

But once i switch to systemctl (sudo systemctl start httpd) subdomain returns 403 error (Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible). `ps aux`:

> apache   23556  0.0  0.0 428700  7676 ?        S    17:00   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND

<strike>So I assume the difference is in -D flag but cannot find any useful info.</strike>

Comment: It seems that -DFOREGROUND does not matter for current case. After manual start with `sudo httpd -DFOREGROUND` vhost works just fine. The problem appears only when using systemctl (systemd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the solution. SELinux blocks some permissions of httpd process. [This](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/SELinux/apache) and [this](https://serverfault.com/a/131131) were helpful.